# Excel- Export specific columns to multiple text files vba

Tags: vba, excel

My excel file looks like this

```
new_filename    MEDIA_ID    SIGHTING_ID FRAME   FACE_X  FACE_Y  FACE_WIDTH
28069_00000.png 28069            15775     0    309.715   16.714    141
28069_00060.png 28069            15776     60   318       17      136.57
28069_00075.png 28069            15777     75   325.857   18        138.571
28069_00135.png 28069            15778     135  343.428   30.5757   134.1428
28069_00195.png 28069            15779     195  323.333   18      155.333
28069_00255.png 28069            15780     255  278.243   15.2857   138
28069_00315.png 28069            15781     315  284       18.8      137.85
```

I would like to extract values from some columns like facex, facey, face width and face height and save the extracted values in a text file having the value in new filename column as the name of the text file.

I would like to repeat the same procedure for almost 3000 rows.

So txt file 1 should have values of (2,c6) (2,c7) (2,c8) and it should be named as (2,c1)
and so on for all the rows. Is it clear enough?

Comment: Help with what?  What *specifically* is the issue preventing you from achieving this ?

Comment: What's wrong with selecting the entire column from "FACE_X" over, copying into a new workbook, and saving?  The amount of rows don't matter.  If you want to determine *which* cells to extract, you could perhaps use an `Index/Match` formula to only show those rows that meet whatever criteria it is.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: You are going to really confuse things if you save text in a file with a `.png` extension.

Comment: Sorry if my question had confused you!  I wanted to extract multiple text files having values of c4,c5,c6 and c7. The name of the txt file should be c1. Is that clear enough?

Comment: I would suggest you loop across each row in your worksheet (starting at 2) and, for each row: `Open` a text file `For Output`, `Join` the required columns together (with a comma separator?), `Print` the combined string to the text file, `Close` the text file.  (Just tested - takes 7 lines of code.)

Comment: Thats sounds about right. can you share the code?

Comment: It would have been more appropriate if you had shared **your** current code in the question, but I will add an answer based on my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Long
    With ActiveSheet

        r = 2
        Do While .Cells(r, 1).Value <> ""
            Open .Parent.Path & "\" & Left(.Cells(r, 1).Value, Len(.Cells(r, 1).Value) - 4) & ".TXT" For Output As #1
            Print #1, .Cells(r, 6).Value & "," & .Cells(r, 7).Value & "," & .Cells(r, 8).Value
            Close #1
            r = r + 1
        Loop

    End With
End Sub
```